# Read string which contains \" from mongodb

Tags: c++, mongodb, mongodb-query

In my MongoDB, I have stored below string

```
"description" : "25\"",
```

But when I try to read it in C++ driver using both ways below, I always get "25""

```
d->description=record.getStringField("description");
```

or

```
d->description = record.getField("description").jsonString(Strict);
```

I need to keep back slash \ here, because the string will be sent to web browser, JavaScript code will parse this string to JSON object.

Any way to do this?

Comment: And your programming language? For the tags.

Comment: I am using C++ mongodb driver

Comment: Interesting. What do you get from .toString()? might be a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how that string got in there, but this will not serialize or deserialize properly without the proper escaping. It should look more like this:

```
 { "description" : "25\\\"" }
```

You should update these with your driver, which should do the serialization properly just based on your regular input, ie `25"`.

When the fields in the document look like above then they will deserialize how you want.

Comment: I did this before you gave the answer, same to you. :)